# Why WiX UI became 33% bigger than original settings even though Windows Display settings is 100%

Tags: wix, wix3

I have started creating my own UI using Dialog.

I have noticed that my background image is scaled and I see jaggy image results.

When I took my screen shot of my dialog, I noticed that the screen width and height is increased by nearly 33.5%. (Forexample the Width that I set as 692 has became 924).

I thought may be my Windows 10 display scale settings is modified, but I can see that it is Recommended 100%.

Would anybody have any clue as to why this may be occuring?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How are you measuring? [Installer units](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369490) are neither pixels nor dialog units.

Comment: Oh it is not pixel? I assumed my value I inputed (692) was pixel. I measured by using the screen capture software and selected the pixel used. If it is not pixel, what should I enter?